# Building other image before core-image-minimal

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, yocto

Thanks for your time and help

I have integrated swupdate in my Yocto Project.

Now, to create software update rescue root file system, I need to first execute the command: `bitbake swupdate-image`

Then I need to execute the command: `bitbake core-image-minimal`

Is there any way that I first execute only `bitbake core-image-minimal`, and it first builds swupdate-image and then core-image-minimal

Thanks again

Comment: You can look [here](https://github.com/sbabic/meta-swupdate-boards/blob/master/recipes-extended/images/update-image.bb) on how to set dependancy between images.

Comment: As of now, I am doing bitbake swupdate-image for generating swupdate rescue system, then bitbake core-image-minimal and then I created a new image for generating the swu file bitbake image-swu. How can I reduce it to one or two commands

Answer (score 0):

You can set in [INITRAMFS_IMAGE](https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/latest/ref-manual/ref-manual.html#var-INITRAMFS_IMAGE) variable `local.conf`:

```
INITRAMFS_IMAGE = "swupdate-image"
```

But as a general rule: one image - one run of bitbake.